# SQL2 query with equality using a backslash

Tags: jcr, jcr-sql2, jackrabbit-oak

## Issue

I have an oak property index on the property `somePath`

When I execute SQL2 queries on this property, like below, I get results:

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] = 'ABC'
```

However, when I put values with a backslash in this query, it cannot find any results, while there are matches in the metadata.

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] =  'F:\path\to\somewhere.jpg'
```

All content is correctly indexed and the index is being used (visible in Explain Query)

## Tryouts

#### ESCAPE operator - FAILURE

I already tried to use the ESCAPE operator from the LIKE command, but this does not work with a simple equality operator.

#### Escape the backslash (JCR SQL2) - FAILURE

When I try to escape the backslash like I found in some dark jcr sql2 documentation ('), I also get no results:

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] =  "F:'\path'\to'\somewhere.jpg"
```

#### Escape the backslash (Java-style) - FAILURE

When I try to escape the backslash java style, I also get no results:

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] =  'F:\\path\\to\\somewhere.jpg'
```

#### URL Encode the backslash - FAILURE

Apply URL encoding to the string, no results:

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] =  'F:%5Cpath%5Cto%5Csomewhere.jpg'
```

#### Use square brackets to escape any characters - FAILURE

Wrap the value in square brackets like with the where clause left operand, no results (both with and without quotes):

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] =  [F:\path\to\somewhere.jpg]
```

#### CAST the value to String - FAILURE

Cast the value explicitly to String, no results:

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where d.[jcr:content/metadata/somePath] =  CAST('F:\path\to\somewhere.jpg' AS STRING)
```

#### Use the CONTAINS operator - WORKAROUND

When I use CONTAINS, I do get results, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d 
where ISDESCENDANTNODE(d, '/content/dam') AND CONTAINS(d.* , 'F:\path\to\somewhere.jpg')
```

Any ideas on how SQL2 deals with property values with backslashes?

Comment: Where are you using the query? Java, JS, ... I tried with crxde query tool and with acs tools explain query. Both worked without escaping.